# I need to save emails from a form on my website, and for some reason I can't get it to save

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, vps

I'm not sure what's going wrong here. Ive been trying to save the emails to a single column table in my MySQL database for hours and cannot figure it out.

Html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="call-to-action text-center">
            <form class="form-inline margin-clear">
                <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="subscribe3">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="subscribe3" placeholder="Enter email" name="subscribe3" required="">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope form-control-feedback"></i>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-gray-transparent btn-animated margin-clear">Subscribe <i class="fa fa-send"></i></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    //checking if data has been entered
    if( isset( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) && !empty( $_POST['subscribe3'] ) )
    {
        $data = $_POST['subscribe3'];
    } else {
        header( 'location: index.html' );
        exit();
    }

    //setting up mysql details
    $sql_server = 'localhost';
    $sql_user = 'root';
    $sql_pwd = '*password*';
    $sql_db = 'newsletter';

    //connecting to sql database
    $mysqli = new mysqli( $sql_server, $sql_user, $sql_pwd, $sql_db ) or die( $mysqli->error );


    //inserting details into table
    $insert = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO email ( `Emails` ) VALUES ( '$data' )" );

    //closing mysqli connection
    $mysqli->close;
?>
```

Final problem is that it ends on a white page. How can I redirect back to the default/home page?

Comment: You need to insert `VALUES`, not `VALUE`.

Comment: While typically you would say `VALUES`, `VALUE` works just fine (at least in recent mysql). Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/815bef/1

Comment: Aside from that, there is only one issue I can see and that is that you aren't specifying a method for the `<form>` tag. That means the form would default to `GET`, not `POST`. Meaning that `$_POST['subscribe3']` would be not set and you would constantly get redirected. When having issues like this, the first thing you should try to do is remove redirects or things like that that might prevent you from seeing errors, second being output debugging messages.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed too, your database connection variable is defined as `myslqi`, a misspelling (`l` and `q` are reversed). Plus `$mysqli->close` is a method (function call), not a property, so it needs parenthesis.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I feel like an idiot :-) How id I not see that, thank you sooo much!!

Comment: For the last error, I mentioned it in my last comment. `->close` is a method, not a property. You need to call it as a method like `$mysqli->close()`. With parenthesis means method (function within a class), without it looks for a property (variable in a class) which in this case won't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query from:

```
$insert = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO email ( `Emails` ) VALUE ( '$data' )" );
```

to:

```
$insert = $mysqli->query( "INSERT INTO email ( `Emails` ) VALUES ( '$data' )" );
```

I know the [MYSQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) show `{VALUES | VALUE}`, but in my experience that has never worked and none of the examples contain "`VALUE`". So a safe bet is that that is your error.

Comment: @amflare It now gives me this error: Notice:                                      Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsletter-signup.php on line 22

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsletter-signup.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsletter-signup.php on line 22

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the submit button to an input of type submit. That way you could change the php as I believe your current code is contradicting itself

The PHP could should look like this

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 if (!empty ($_POST['subscribe3'])
 {
  $data = trim ($_POST['subscribe3']);
 } else
 {
  header ('location: index.html');
  exit();
 }
}
```

To reiterate this would only work if you change your submit button from a button to an input

Hope this helps